# Performing table look-up using Python in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, dictionary

Using ArcGIS 10.1 the arcpy module has a [TableToNumPyArray](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000018000000) command, which converts a table into an array.

Unfortunately I don't have access to 10.1 on my work PC. Is there a workaround which will accomplish this using ArcGIS 10.0?

**Background**

I'm iterating through features in a featureclass, and I need to look-up a price depending on an attribute value.

I need to find a price for multiple fields per feature, so I can't use a table join. I can't create a relationship class as I only have an ArcView license.

A messy workaround could be to load the table into a searchCursor and iterate through each record until I find the desired value. But this would be intensive as I'd need to work through the searchCursor for every feature in the featureclass.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A workaround for not having the TableToNumPyArray command would be this:

- First, iterate through all features in your feature class, and store the price data in a Python dictionary.
- Second, iterate again through all features in your feature class, and just lookup your price data from the dictionary.

Instead of the processing time for n features being n*n, it will just be n*2. Here's some code:

```
import arcpy

PriceDictionary = {}

MyCursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("MyLayer")
for Feature in MyCursor:
    PriceDictionary[Feature.getValue("ID")] = Feature.getValue("Price")
del Feature
del MyCursor

LookupCursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor("MyLayer")
for Feature in LookupCursor:
    Feature.setValue("NewPrice",PriceDictionary[Feature.getValue("LookupField")])
del Feature
del LookupCursor
```

If you're not familiar with dictionaries, check out [this tutorial on dictionaries](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/index.html). For reference, using Python dictionaries and other data structures in clever ways is often *much* faster than using their arcpy counterparts. If your script is going slowly, try to remove as many arcpy commands as you can.